# Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded, can't change max_execution_time

Tags: php, xampp

I'm running a Wordpress installaction on localhost, using xampp.

I made a backup using WP Clone plugin, and now i'm trying to restore it on my localhost version.

After some time, i get the message:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\sbc\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 217
```

I tried this several times, and i get the same error always. The only difference is it happens on different files.

I tried changing the value of max_execution_time from 30 to 1000 in php.ini (and restarting xampp afterwards) and it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're changing the correct ini.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

You can also change the value in the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 1000
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you explain? Where should i put phpinfo()?

I didn't find .htaccess file, and i created one in htdocs folder, but i still get the same error. Always 300 seconds error.

Comment: Create a php file called test.php with that code and check it in your browser and then do a search for the max execution time to see if it reflects your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Funny thing happened. I managed to restore the clone, when I used the server URL.
The first couple of times i tried, the backup file was on my localhost, and for some reason it didn't work that way, so it was giving me the 300 seconds limit error, although the value vas not correct (i created test.php, and all max_execution_time changes were correctly noted there).